# meaning of "add mappable to an Axes"

Tags: python, matplotlib

Recently I ran an old code and Matplotlib told me

> ```
> MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
> Unable to determine Axes to steal space for Colorbar.
> Using gca(), but will raise in the future.
> Either provide the *cax* argument to use as the Axes for the Colorbar,
> provide the *ax* argument to steal space from it,
> =============================
> or add *mappable* to an Axes.
> =============================
> ```

Well, I understand the problem and the `cax` and `ax` solutions –I have already fixed my old code– but I don't understand the "add `mappable` to an Axes" part, at least in the context of the MWE below.

Could you **explain the meaning of  "*add `mappable` to an Axes*"**?

---

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 201)
sm = ScalarMappable(norm=plt.Normalize(0.5, 4.5), cmap='cool_r')
for i in range(4):
    plt.plot(x, x+(1-x)*np.sin(np.pi*i*x), color=sm.to_rgba(i+1))
cb = plt.colorbar(sm)
cb.set_ticks((1,2,3,4))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, a "mappable" is a graphical element, typically something image-like or a set of scatter dots, that is colored by mapping a list of given values via a norm and colormap to a range of colors. So, here I suppose is meant that if such a "mappable" graphical element, is given as parameter to `plt.colorbar()` and that element would also belong to a given subplot, matplotlib can figure out which subplot to steal space from. If, on the other hand, you create such a graphical element without adding it to a certain plot, matplotlib stays into doubt.